# No Module find in Deployment Package for AWS Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, import, aws-lambda

I installed ujson package in virtualenv

```
(mylambdaenv) C:\Users\xyz\lambda_code\mylambdaenv>pip install ujson
    Collecting ujson
      Using cached ujson-4.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (43 kB)
    Installing collected packages: ujson
    Successfully installed ujson-4.0.2
```

But While running the package it is failing with error no module ujson. I have one file in my package as **ujson.cp36-win_amd64** & one folder **ujson-4.0.2.dist-info**. Is it not readable by AWS Lambda? Please help to resolve
Error

```
import ujson
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ujson'
```

Comment: Your package seem to be for windows `win_amd64`. Lambda does not work with windows packages.

Comment: Can you help me to manually install ujson

Comment: Sure. I will provide answer with instructions. it will involve docker though, but it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way, in my experience, to add dependencies to lambda functions is through [lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) and the use of **docker tool** described in the recent **AWS blog**:

- [How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)

Thus you can add `ujson` to your function as follows:

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`.
2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt` file with the content of

```
echo ujson > ./requirements.txt
```

3. Run the following docker command:

The command will create layer for python3.8:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Archive the layer as zip:

```
zip -9 -r mylayer.zip python
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `mylayer.zip` in the AWS Console. Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtime` to `python3.8`.
6. Add the the layer created in step 6 to your function.
7. Test the layer in lambda using the following lambda function:

```
import ujson

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print(dir(ujson))
```

I tested this and it the function and layer work **correctly**:

```
['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'decode', 'dump', 'dumps', 'encode', 'load', 'loads']
```

p.s.

The above steps were executed on linux. If you don't have one, you can create EC2 linux instance and do the steps there if you wish.